# How to nest python lists recursively?

Tags: python, nested-lists

```
list0 = [[]]
list0[0].append([])
list0[0][0].append([])
list0[0][0][0].append(["I'm in deep!"])
print(list0)
```

How do I achieve the nested effect above in a loop? Like how I can append lists to a list in a loop.

```
def list_deepener(layers):
    list1 = [[]]
    count = 0
    while count != layers:
        count += 1
        y = "list1" + ("[0]" * count)
        y.append([])
        print(x)
list_deepener(5)
```

I tried this but I couldn't think of any way to convert the string into code which would allow me to alter list1.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. " I couldn't think of any way to convert the string into code which would allow me to alter list1." Trying to convert a string into code does not make sense for this problem. Instead, try a completely different approach. Hint: suppose that after some iteration of the loop, `y` is another name for `list1[0]`, and it should become `list1[0][0]` in order to continue. How could you write code to do that, taking advantage of the existing value of `y`? Do you see how and why that same code would give you the right result every time through the loop?

Answer (score 1):

You could pass a range and initial string to [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) for a simple one-liner:

```
from functools import reduce

layers = 4

reduce(lambda a, _: [a], range(layers), "I'm in deep!")
# [[[["I'm in deep!"]]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that we have `mylist = []` to begin with, and we want to add lists to a certain depth. The trick is to use a separate variable to *keep track of where we are in the nesting process*, and update that variable as we add each layer. Thus:

```
>>> mylist = []
>>> current = mylist
>>> for i in range(5):
...     to_add = []
...     current.append(to_add)
...     current = to_add
... 
>>> mylist # 6 pairs of brackets: the initial list, plus 5 added nested lists
[[[[[[]]]]]]
```

Comment: [walrus version](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P7cyJ7O4RMFWIbm0qCg1D8SKjuVKyy9SyFTIzFMoSsxLT9Uw1bTiUgACqBq9xIKC1LwUDZgWK5AeTS6ugqLMvBINiIma//8DAA)

Answer (score 0):

There's many ways to solve this issue, but when you find yourself constructing code in strings and looking for ways to execute that, you're on the wrong path.

A recursive solution:

```
def nest(x, levels):
    assert levels >= 0
    if levels == 0:
        return [x]
    else:
        return [nest(x, levels-1)]


print(nest("I'm in deep", 5))
```

An iterative solution:

```
def nest(x, levels):
    assert levels >= 0
    result = [x]
    for _ in range(levels):
        result = [result]
    return result


print(nest("I'm in deep", 5))
```

Comment: Thank You so much bro! This warning has kept me from the string path like a dozen times.

Comment: You're welcome, happy to hear it - future you and others looking at your code will thank you ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to think about this is recursively. Consider what you want in the deepest part of your list (your 'base' case') and then layer on top for each iteration.

```
def deepen(layers: int) -> list:
    if layers <= 1:  # Base case, i.e. 'what happens at the bottom'
        return ["Deeper than deep"]
    else:  # Iterative case, i.e. 'what happens at each layer'
        return [deepen(layers - 1)]
```

This gives you the correct result:

```
>>> def deepen(layers: int) -> list:
...     if layers <= 1:
...         return ["Deeper than deep"]
...     else:
...         return [deepen(layers - 1)]
...
>>> deepen(5)
[[[[['Deeper than deep']]]]]
```